# Safe alternative to "name" attribute in <a>

Tags: html

In the past, you would use `<a name="example">` to create an anchor which you could jump to by adding `#example` to the url.

However, this is being removed in HTML 5, with the "official" alternative being to use `id` instead.

This is not acceptable when dealing with user-generated content, since it could interfere with other elements on the page. With `name`, the worst that will happen is the link won't work, but conflicting `id`s could break styles and scripts as well.

Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: `name` attributes can break styles and scripts too. You should include fixing up id attributes as part of your general sanitization of user-generated content.

Comment: Well you could add diffrent attributes like field-name then submit it with a function that you build upp a dynamic FORM and translate the field-name to name

Comment: If you're worried about interfering with other content, consider adding a prefix to all user-generated names. If the user submits `example`, store it as `content-example`.